# Console log not showing any new logs and showing logs that are not in my code

Tags: vue.js, router, console.log

thank you for your time!
I am working on buildings a small webapp and I have run into an issue where I am trying to fetch data from a JSON and display this information into cards on my page. This all works fine and I use `console.log('Fetched data:', items.value)` to show that the data is being correctly read into my webapp from the JSON.
However, whenever  try to add new console logs to my function, they don't print in the console log, and even if I remove the console log I have, it still prints in the console. I've also noticed that if I add any new headings to the template like

#### Hello

, they don't print on the webpage either. So I get the feeling that no changes from my Vue code are actually being reflected on the webpage, even though any changes to my other vue pages in the app do reflect on the webpage.

I have a feeling that there might be an issue in the router. I am using Vuestic-admin package and have edited the router details for the "enquiries" page (which is the unresponsive one I'm have issues with).

index.ts in Router file:
`{ name: 'enquiries', path: 'enquiries', component: () => import('../pages/admin/landing/projects/Projects.vue'), },`

gb.json in i18n file:
  `"projects": "Enquiries",`

NavigationRoutes.ts in sidebar component:
  `{ name: 'enquiries', displayName: 'menu.enquiries', meta: { icon: 'vuestic-iconset-forms', }, },`

I am not sure how to fix this error, and any advice would be much appreciated. If you need more information, please let me know and I would be happy to answer. Thank you so much again for your time.